# Changing browser zoom level when using selenium grid

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

Currently using selenium (in Java) for automated testing. When running the tests on a selenium grid, the window size changes to a window much smaller than my local (I have no control over the window size when doing a grid run). The smaller window width during the grid run causes the page objects to move in the HTML, changing their references (xpaths, css selectors, etc.). This causes the code to throw a bunch of null pointers. Any ideas on how to get around this? I need a solution that works in Chrome/Firefox/IE

Since I am unable to change the window size, the best solution I've come up with is to zoom out the browser when doing a grid run, moving the objects back into place. I'm using selenium 4.0.0-alpha-1 and tried the following approaches:

1. Actions class:

```
new Actions(driver).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.SUBTRACT)).perform();
```

2. Targeting the html tag with the Actions class:

```
new Actions(driver).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")),
Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.SUBTRACT)).perform();
```

3. Targeting the html tag with the webdriver:

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("html"))
.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.SUBTRACT));
```

4. Using javascript:

```
engine.javaScript.execute("document.body.style.zoom = '75%'");
engine.javaScript.execute("document.body.style.webkitTransform='scale(.75)'");
```

5. Using the Robot class:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SUBTRACT);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SUBTRACT);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

--

Methods 1-3 don't work locally or on the grid.

Method 4 works on all browsers (used webkitTransform since its supported across all 3) but it zooms out the CSS and not the browser itself, so the objects remain in the same place despite being zoomed out.

Method 5 works across all browsers locally, but when running on the grid, it nothing happens because I believe the robot needs a GUI to interact with.

Most answers to this question are over 2 years old and don't seem to work anymore, would appreciate any help or if there is another solution to getting around the window sizing. Trying to get around creating separate object references specifically for the grid.

Comment: If I understood correctly .you want to keep window size same across local and remote node.You can fix the window size by providing window size when creating the browser session on grid .In chrome "--window-size=1920,1080"

Comment: Hey Rahul, thanks for the reply. I have tried resetting the window size (I have a maximize function that runs when the web driver starts up) but the max window width on the grid is 1000px while my local screen is around 1350px. This is causing the objects to move and change their xpath/css selector from when I coded on my local.

Comment: Maximizing the Windows will not help .For test you will have to select some criteria of windows size.Your application must be having some requirements related to ViewPort.